# Access User Control from Parent

Tags: c#, webforms

On the HomePage.aspx, i have a usercontrol, Product.acsx on this control have another user control ProductDetails.acsx. ProductDetails has a textbox, txtDescription. Product.ascx has a dropdown Products. I am populating the Products dropdown from HomePage.aspx. By default first value is selected, there is no empty value. If the first value which is auto selected is Electronics, then i need to disable the textbox: txtDescription on the ProductDetails.acsx. How to access txtDescription on HomePage.aspx.

2nd Approach: By the time Product.acsx is loaded Electronics is selected in the dropdown, how to make txtDescription disabled.

Note: Dropdown has other values, Returns, Enquiry, Electronics, Home Appliances. It's not necessary Electronics is always the first value.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I created a public method, `M1()`, in `Product.acsx.cs`, and exposed it to `HomePage.aspx.cs`. `M1()` has access to the textbox: `txtDescription`.

Please share if you have a better approach.